# publish website to Raspberry Pi 3 from Pycharm and Django

Tags: django, raspberry-pi, pycharm

I'm developing a website from Pycharm and Django on Window but I don't know how to publish it to Raspberry Pi 3.
Can anyone have any idea

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Pi 3 already has the environment setup, if all you are looking for is to deploy the files, you can use scp (secure copy) to copy the files from Windows to Pi. You can use a client tool like WinSCP in Windows.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm totally new with python, pycharm and pi. Do you have any document, video example?